# SimpleXML remove multiple nodes by index

Tags: php, simplexml

I want to remove specific indexes from an xml file and save it back.

```
<channel>
  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>baz</item>
  <item>foo</item>
  ...
  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>baz</item>
  <item>foo</item>
</channel>
```

I have an array of indexes

```
$indexes_to_remove = array(3,12,17);
```

I load the file and loop over the indexes and try to unset

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('content.xml');

foreach($indexes_to_remove as $id){
    unset($xml->channel->item[(int)$id][0]);
}
file_put_contents('content.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Items get removed but not the right ones (not all of them). I believe it's because while unsetting the simple xml index gets messed up.

I've looked over existing questions and I've also tried

```
foreach($indexes_to_remove as $id){
    $result = $xml->xpath( "(//item)[$id]" );
    foreach ( $result as $node ) {
        $dom = dom_import_simplexml($node);
        $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
    }
}
file_put_contents('content.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

Same result. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try `$indexes_to_remove = rsort(array(3,12,17));` as you want to `unset` indexes from large to small.

Comment: nice. rsort fixed it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

**content.xml**

```
<channel>
  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>3rd value</item>
  <item>foo</item>

  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>baz</item>
  <item>foo</item>

  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>baz</item>
  <item>12th value</item>

  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>baz</item>
  <item>foo</item>

  <item>17th value</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>baz</item>
  <item>foo</item>
</channel>
```

**php**

```
$indexes_to_remove = array(3,12,17);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('content.xml', 'SimpleXMLElement');
if($xml->item){
    $rindex = 0;
    foreach($indexes_to_remove as $index){   
        $index += $rindex; // changing index after removed the node
        $dom = $xml->xpath('/channel/item['.$index.']');
        $dom = dom_import_simplexml($dom[0]);   
        $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
        $rindex--;               
    }
}
file_put_contents('content.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

**output**

```
<channel>
  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>foo</item>

  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>baz</item>
  <item>foo</item>

  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>baz</item>

  <item>foo</item>
  <item>bar</item>
  <item>baz</item>
  <item>foo</item>

  <item>bar</item>
  <item>baz</item>
  <item>foo</item>
</channel>
```